# How to re-route a form to another page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So I am a bit rusty on my Rails and can't seem to figure this out. I created an ActionMailer that I set up with SendGrid on Heroku and it works, but not where I want it to. If I go to my website: `example.com/messages/new` I see a form, fill it out, hit submit and I get an email. However, I have a form in my `root_path` that I want to do the same thing. When I try `<%= form_for @message do |f| %>` it is not finding the params. This is clearly a controller / action issue, since the params are in the other path, but how do I tell the app to redirect the params to a different route?

Comment: Have you set `@message` in the controller action of your root_path? Or you might want to replace it with `Message.new` in your root_path's partial

Comment: @Sillico, please post your controller code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can overwrite the conventions by specifying a url like this

```
<%= form_for(@message, url: messages_path) do |f| %>
 ...
<% end %>
```